# Adaptive software on Ubuntu for the blind?

Tags: system-installation

I am a blind computer user  Who is  A lifelong Windows user who is looking at other operating systems.  On windows are use third-party installed speech programs to make my computer talk but at the very minimum I need a speech program similar to window's narrator or Mac's voiceover and I was wondering if anyone could tell me if  Ubuntu  has adaptive software built-in like the other operating systems.  I know almost nothing about Linux at all but I'm interested in learning so I'm contemplating installing it on a virtual machine and playing around with it to see how it would work for me but I'm wondering if it has any speech software similar to the other operating systems that could help me during the installation?

Answer (score 1):

Well I hope I'm not too late for being helpful here but Windows refugees looking into Linux need look no further than Ubuntu.
The first lesson you need is changing terminology, simply understand that the Windows Key or Start Key as we call is is now the Super Key.  So Super Key+Alt+S will start Orca Screen Reader on any version of Ubuntu Desktop since version 10 or 12 as far as I know.
This means that if you can get your BIOS or UEFI set up to boot from a USB first then you're half way done already.  If you don't have that setup you'll likely need a lot of luck or some sighted help.  Once you boot from the Ubuntu installation media then you can launch Orca as I mentioned above and it will speak to you throughout the installation process.  Furthermore this will inform Ubuntu that you are using the Orca Screen Reader and tell it to launch Orca automatically at the next restart.

So if you want to be on the cutting edge then you can just install normal Ubuntu Desktop and run with it.  You'll want to make sure you're jumping on an LTSB version though, the Long Term Servie Branch has all of the stable goodies to do pretty much anything you want anyways.

With respect to the other post in this thread, Vinux is pretty much the only viable option for already setup to work with blindness Linux flavors.  I used to do a lot of work with Sonar and the gang from there joined forces with Vinux, which I might add is based on Ubuntu 16 LTSB version.  The Vinux OS is a little more restrictive than I like, but it does work pretty good as far as ready to rock and roll right out of the box.

Another option is Talking Arch which is based on Arch Linux.  If you like to try new and crazy things just to see if you brick your PC then dive into Talking Arch without looking and enjoy the heck out of it!!!!
Here's a tip, read the Arch Linux installation tutorial like 30 times before jumping in though!!!

I'm blind and I've used both Linuxand Windows since Ubuntu version 8 I think so I can promise you between normal LTSB Linux Desktop an Vinux those are your 2 most stable, actually supported and fully functional options.
Also, ask Google about Orca Screen Reader, read up on it and make sure you understand how to use it and how to change settings for it.

HTH
Tiki

Answer (score 0):

There are two options I found in this regard:

1. Installing a Linux OS that is made specifically for the physically impaired, and
2. Installing screen readers into an existing Linux OS

In the first case, the following OS are available:

1. [Vinux](http://vinuxproject.org/), based on Ubuntu
2. [Sonar](http://sonargnulinux.com/), based on Arch Linux
3. [Knoppix ADRIANE](http://www.knopper.net/knoppix-adriane/index-en.html), based on Debian

And for the second situation look at this article and see which works for you:

http://usabilitygeek.com/10-free-screen-reader-blind-visually-impaired-users/

I have never tried any of them, so I can provide any technical specifications but I believe the first option to install a Linux made specifically for the impaired would a better decision.